# How cloud spring boot uses properties in yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud-aws

When using Spring Cloud AWS for a repo, I noticed application.yml contains

```
spring:
  profiles: aws
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
aws:
  paramstore:
    prefix: /micro
    name: microapp
    profileSeparator: #
    enabled: true
```

But I couldn't find where these properties are used. Usually, yml properties are imported via @Value or @ConfigurationProperties, but here there's no such an annotation used for them in the repo.

The pom.xml file had `spring-cloud-starter-aws` and `spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config` dependencies, which I guessed used the properties.

Whenever I added a custom property, such as `aws.smb.enable`, pom.xml complained of 'unknown properties'.

I don't actually know how the properties in the yaml file work with Spring Cloud AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I couldn't find where these properties are used. Usually, yml properties are imported via @Value or @ConfigurationProperties, but here there's no such an annotation used for them in the repo.

Which repo are you looking in? The `aws` properties are read in the Spring Cloud AWS project. For example, the `aws.paramstore` properties are read in [`org.springframework.cloud.aws.paramstore.AwsParamStoreProperties` using `@ConfigurationProperties`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/paramstore/AwsParamStoreProperties.java).

All of the `aws` and `cloud.aws` properties are documented in the [Spring Cloud AWS docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/reference/html/appendix.html#common-application-properties).